# Power button goes on but screen won't open up

Tags: windows

So I was opening my laptop when I noticed that the monitor won't open or light up even though my power button, caps lock and f12 key on. My laptop is HP C62 (Pavilion C62? I don't know). The caps lock is blinking by the way. I was expecting that its just the LCD was broken but if the LCD was broken, wouldn't the laptop would played the startup sound already? Because I've been waiting for 5 minutes for it to turn on but yeah.

So my main question/s is/are:
1. Is my laptop broken? Or just the LCD?

Answer (score 1):

Google really doesn't seem to recognize an HP C62, but seems to suggest an HP G62.  According to [this image of an HP G62](https://driverbasket.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/HP-G62.jpg), the left side has some I/O ports and the one furthest towards the back is a VGA-style connector.

Most laptops do have some sort of monitor connector.  Just plug in a compatible monitor, and see if you get video.

If you do, try to tell your computer to flip back to the LCD display.  Holding down the Start key (which often has a Windows logo) and pressing P will often help on newer versions of Microsoft Windows (by showing a menu: you could then use the mouse, or try pressing Down Arrow one to three times, and then pressing Enter.)

Another common option is for laptops to have some special key combination for flipping between LCD and monitor.  e.g., maybe hold down a key called "Fn", and press the F7 key.  On such laptops, the F7 key was usually labelled (on the key, or right above it) with a picture of a couple of squares that overlapped (one a bit further up-and-right of the other), with those squares sometimes having a couple of lines under them (a vertical line sitting on a horizontal line, meant to mimic a monitor's stand).

I wouldn't be quick to draw conclusions about hearing no sound.  The computer might just have sound at a low level, even muted, or piping sound to a headphone jack, or may not even have an active sound device that the operating system supports.

Comment: My sound isn't muted since my last shutdown. I'm remembering it's 100. My last doings is turning on the Windows Update because my laptop didn't receive updates for a long time.

Comment: pardon too you're correct it's G62